# What is this plane?

Tags: aircraft-identification

What is this plane? It kept circling overhead and I managed to get a picture during one of it's passes. The only parts I could see was 4 piston engines, straight wings, and a tall tail with some obscure markings on it.

[image: Pretty Picture of An Airplane in the sky.]

Comment: As the answer below says, it is unmistakably a C-130 Hercules military transport. It has 4 turboprop engines, not piston engines.

Comment: It least I figured out the engines used big propellers...

Comment: This wouldn't happen to be near the Peoria Air National Guard would it?

Comment: Circling overhead? I'm slightly disappointed it wasn't an AC-130 ;-)

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick That would have been spooky...

Comment: Indeed it would, @SteveIves, indeed it would... :)

Comment: There is a horizontal stripe across the tail. So this airplane is most likely Air National Guard. Inside that stripe will be the state name but the photo is not clear enough to read. Wikipedia for the 169th Airlift Squadron says they fly C-130H3, but the photo is a J model, you can tell by the propeller blades.

Comment: @radarbob, the first picture in answer by veryRandomMe appears to have the same stripe, but the wing is clearly marked "USAF", so not (necessarily) National Guard. Or do ANG aircraft carry that designation too?

Comment: You're  right about the stripe - looking on c-130.net I see a Little Rock AFB bird with a stripe: "The Rock" and "AMC" (Air Mobility Command) directly above that. It is definitely active duty, not guard. ; but in the reference photo  I see "ANG" above that stripe. And on the wheel well blister I see " ... GUARD" which is(!) ANG-specific.  All I know is, when I went out to the parking lot I always found my airplane.

Comment: Air Guard planes also have national symbology - the stars and bars; and USAF. But that was long ago and far away, I saw so much better than I do today.

Answer (score 20):

This looks like a C-130, as features like the bulge for the landing gear make it fairly easy to make the comparison.

For reference, here is a C-130 in flight:

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

The first image even appears to have the same markings as shown in the footage.

Military practices quite often will require an aircraft to hold a position, and could have just been circling for that reason. These aircraft are primarily used for lifting and aerial refueling. I do not see any refueling pods on the reference though, so it appears to be an unconverted plane.

Comment: that looks exactly like it - even the paint on the tail matches!